# Ember deserialization breaking URL with null

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a basic router for posts index and show action. If I navigate to a single post, it renders the page correctly and sets the URL to `/#/posts/foo`. But if I copy the URL and paste it into a new tab, it will load the page, but the url will change to `/#/posts/null`. Other than that the page is rendered properly and no errors are shown

```
show: Em.Route.extend({
  route: "/post/:id",

  serialize: function(router, context) {
    return { id: context.get("id") };
  },

  deserialize: function(router, context) {
    return App.get("store").find(App.Post, context.id);
  },

  connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
    router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet("body", "post", context);
  }
})
```

with a simple model

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  id:      DS.attr("string"),
  title:   DS.attr("string"),
  content: DS.attr("string"),
  image:   DS.attr("string")
});
```

and the log looks like this

```
STATEMANAGER: Entering root ember.js:17420
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'navigateAway' to state root. ember.js:17172
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'unroutePath' to state root. ember.js:17172
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'routePath' to state root. ember.js:17172
STATEMANAGER: Entering root.show
```

and a router

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 4,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
    bulkCommit: false
  })
});
```

Comment: I think your `deserialize` function isn't working properly. Not sure what the problem is, but I'll come back to this later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was specifying `id` as an attrirbute. You should never do that and let Ember Data take care of it automatically.

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title:   DS.attr("string"),
  content: DS.attr("string"),
  image:   DS.attr("string")
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your route should be '/post/:post_id' instead of 'post/:id'. The parameter name is composed of the decapitalized model name, an underscore and the attribute name.

Doing this way you don't need serialize/deserialize method, Ember.js will do the job for you

Comment: Turns out you were kind of right. If I put `/post/:post_id` I don't have to use serialize anymore, but it still does replace with null if I reload the page.